# Remove selected attributes in WEKA

Tags: database, weka

I am creating a scatterplot of countries with most hotel cancelations and i have accumulated alot of data from various countries and when i visualize the data it does translate well so i need to remove most of the countries from the country attribute but it wont seem to let me do it very easily
[image: shows the country attribute with the specific countries as selected attributes]

[image: scatter plot of countries and the months with most cancelations which has not translated well as there are too many countries]

I tried using the 'removewithvalue' filter but it is a very time consuming process when there are 178 different countries and it doesn't specifically remove the selected attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RemoveWithValues](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/instance/RemoveWithValues.html) removes the rows in the data of the label indices of the attribute that you've specified. Unless you specify the `-H/modifyHeader` option/property to also remove these labels from the attribute definition, the predefined labels will still be present as valid labels, but with 0 occurences.